# Voice and video calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I wanted to know, if I am on a voice call or video call on Facebook Messenger, does it show me as online?

If so, is there a way I can appear as offline whilst on the call?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not turn off chat, yes, it will show you online when you are on call.

You can turn off chat and call anyone voice or video.

Once you turn off chat, you will not be able to see who is online and your friends also will not see that you are online.

**Note:** You may still be shown as available if you're active on Messenger.

You can turn off chat for all the contact or for few of your friends.

[Turn chat on or off on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/215888465102253)

Comment: Thanks for that serene! One other question then, if I do turn off my chat can other people still see my last timestamp for when I was on messenger or will say nothing?

Comment: If you turn off chat, I think it will not show anything.

Comment: Thank you! If anyone could test this out or confirm this whilst on a video/voice call it would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Last seen will show, it is a feature of Facebook. You have to logout from all the devices, specially from the app to [hide your last seen](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-hide-my-last-seen-online-time-in-Facebook/answer/Satyendra-Shukla-6?srid=7Iht).